# Parsing XML that is missing expected child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am parsing an XML fragment using LINQ to XML and I am finding one of the nodes I am selecting is missing the child nodes I am expecting.

**Example XML**

```
<CustomerList>
  <Customer>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <FirstName>Todd</FirstName>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <LastName>Jones</LastName>
    <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>Tom Jones</Customer> <!-- Missing child nodes -->
</CustomerList>
```

When I try and pull out the `LastName` and `FirstName` values I get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**Parsing XML with LINQ**

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponse);
List<CustomerModel> nodeList = xml.Descendants("CustomerList")
                          .Descendants("Customer")
                          .Select(x => new CustomerModel
                          {
                            LastName = x.Element("LastName").Value,
                            FirstName = x.Element("FirstName").Value,
                          }).ToList<CustomerModel>();
```

In the cases where the `<Customer>` nodes do not have the `<LastName>` and `<FirstName>` nodes how do I skip over them  or better yet not even select them in the first place?

Comment: You could add a `.Where(x => x.Element("LastName") != null && x.Element("FirstName") != null)` before the `.Select()`

Comment: @dcg you meant to say ``.Where(x => x.Element("LastName") != null)``

Comment: @RandRandom You're  right, I'll edit the comment. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest just simply use ``?.Value``

Comment: Cannot you work with a schema to validate the XML?

Comment: @RandRandom - I am parsing an XML fragment and there is no schema to validate against. Can you explain a bit further what you mean by `?.Value`? Thanks.

Comment: instead of ``LastName = x.Element("LastName").Value`` use ``LastName = x.Element("LastName")?.Value,`` this will take care of the null reference object, but it will result in a ``CustomerModel`` with a null ``LastName``, you than have to take care of that.

Comment: @dcg can you make that an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: @RandRandom - Thanks for the follow up explanation. That makes sense.

Comment: You could also change your query to ``xml.Descendants("CustomerList").Descendants("Customer").Where(x => x.HasElements).Select(xxxx);`` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.haselements(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was suggesting is:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponse);
List<CustomerModel> nodeList = xml.Descendants("CustomerList")
                      .Descendants("Customer")
                      .Where(x => x.Element("LastName") != null && x.Element("FirstName") != null)
                      .Select(x => new CustomerModel
                      {
                        LastName = x.Element("LastName").Value,
                        FirstName = x.Element("FirstName").Value,
                      }).ToList<CustomerModel>();
```